# how Asp.net MVC partialview can be cached on the base of parameter

Tags: asp.net-mvc

```
 public PartialViewResult res(int days)
```

I want to cache this partialview on the base of parameter pass to this result.if parameter goes different then cache are seprate for every different parameter passed to action.

are i can destroy this cache before time period. can a access this cache made in it.

Comment: I'd just to clarify the question, as it could be interpreted in different ways. 
Do you want to be able to specifiy how long to cache the partialview for, by setting the number of days in the parameter - or do you want to have the cache keep separate versions for each of the values that 'days' can have. i.e. `someurl?days=1` is cached separately from `someurl?days=7`?

Comment: Judging from the 2 answers provided so far, it looks like I was right to ask for clarifications?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not really clear what you really want. I thought about 2 applications.

```
    public class OutputCacheExt : OutputCacheAttribute
    {
        public string DaysFromParam { get; set; }
        public int Days
        {
            get { return TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Duration).Days; }
            set { Duration = (int)TimeSpan.FromDays(value).TotalSeconds; }
        }
        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(DaysFromParam))
            {
                int days = 0;
                int.TryParse(filterContext.HttpContext.Request[DaysFromParam], out days);
                Days = days;
            }
            base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
        }
    }
```

First application: If you want just set cache in days:

```
[OutputCacheExt(VaryByParam="none", Days=5)]
public PartialViewResult res(int days){}
```

Second application: If you want set days from http param:

```
[OutputCacheExt(VaryByParam="none", DaysFromParam="days")]
public PartialViewResult res(int days){}
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope I have understood your question. In order for you to do caching in asp.net mvc you use the output cache attribute as follows:

[OutputCache(Duration=10, VaryByParam="none")]
public PartialViewResult res(int days)
In this case the Duration is 10 seconds.

Hope it answers your question